# Getting the index of a random item in a list and the index next to it?

Tags: python, list, class, indexing

I'm probably going about this in the wrong way but in this scenario how do I obtain the index of the random item in the list, and how to compare it to the index of the random item +1? i know if it was the last item in the list this would not work, however lets ignore that for now.

```
import random
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataItem = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"]
    def Function1(self):
        self.randomItem = random.choice(self.dataItem)
        #if self.dataItem[self.randomItem] > self.dataItem[self.randomItem +1]:
        return True
v1 = Test()
print(v1.Function1())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to get a random *list item*, you could just use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) to get a random *list index*.

You could also make sure that way that you get an index before the last element, so there is always a *next* element you could compare it to:

```
index = random.randrange(len(self.dataItem) - 1)
if self.dataItem[index] > self.dataItem[index + 1]:
    return True
```

Comment: And what if `index` is the last element of the list?

Comment: Wow thats awesome, thank you! one question, what does the -1 do at the end of (len(self.dataItem)?

Comment: @kerberonix You have that in the post: *make sure that way that you get an index before the last element*